# How to put auto-run on device off?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, device

I have a phone and when I connect that to my computer and then in Android Studio press "run" it will automatically run on my device. Unfortanetely, I want it to run on an emulator. So I disconnected my phone and pressed "run" again. But now it says: "Error running app: No target device found."

How to put off that it only can run on my device? I have different emulators! When I run other apps made in Android Studio I get a screen where I can choose between my real device and an emulator, that's what I want! Thanks already!

Answer (score 1):

you can go to `Run` in the toolbar click the `General` tab then under `Deployment Target Options` in the `Target` drop down choose the option to `Show Device Chooser Dialog` then everytime you run your app you will have to choose what you want it to run on (emulator or device)